# Separate a string with space

Tags: java, string, split

I've seen various methods to split a string. I've tryed with both  from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732790/android-split-string) post.

I'm trying to read and split the next string: `{2b 00 00}`

I see that the most common case is to split a message separated by ":", but in this case, my message is separated by spaces.

Trying both ways, with the regular `split()` function or with the `StringTokenizer` I'm getting a "nullpointerexception" that I supose that is cause because of the space:

```
private String splitReceivedString(String s) {
    String[] separated = s.split(" ");
    return separated[1];
}
```

How could I get the values of this kind of string?

**ADDED CODE WITH THE POSSIBLE PROBLEM**

After checking some of your answers, I do realize that the problem comes from the bluetooth inputstream. I'm getting null values from it. So, here is the code that I'm using to receive the messages:

The code is almost the same than the bluetoothChat example. But it is modified to adapt to my program, so may I have something wrong.

I've got an MCU wich returns me this String `{2b 00 00}` when I send to it another String. I think that this is done in the `connectedThread`:

```
public class ConnectedThread extends Thread {

   public void run() {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
    int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

    /**Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs*/
    while (true) {
        try {
            /**Read from the InputStream*/
            bytes = GlobalVar.mmInStream.read(buffer);

            /**Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity*/
            GlobalVar.mHandler.obtainMessage(GlobalVar.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer).sendToTarget();
```

So, this is sending me the string to the handler function in the main activity:

```
    public final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case GlobalVar.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                //The code here is irelevant
            case  GlobalVar.MESSAGE_WRITE:
                byte[] writeBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                /**construct a string from the buffer*/
                String writeMessage = new String(writeBuf);
                GlobalVar.mCommunicationArrayAdapter.add(writeMessage);
                break;
            case  GlobalVar.MESSAGE_READ:
                byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                /**construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer*/
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf);
                GlobalVar.mCommunicationArrayAdapter.add(readMessage);
                GlobalVar.readString = readMessage;                    
                break;
```

Then, the variable `GlobalVar.readString` is the one that I'm getting in the split function:

```
    private String splitReceivedString (String s) {

        String[] separated = s.split(" ");
        return separated[1];
    }

    receive1 = splitReceivedString (GlobalVar.readString);
```

So, the thing is that it isn't reading right the received string, and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I bet you're passing `null` to the method.

Comment: @arshajii What do you mean? I've readed the String that I want to split with a toast and is exaclty `2b 00 00`

Comment: @arshajii is correct, I tested this method and it works fine.  The String your passing in is either different than `{2b 00 00}` or you are passing in null.

Comment: Clearly it isn't, because if it was you wouldn't get that exception.

Comment: Use debugger to ensure what u are passing

Comment: answered in @chiccodoro's answer

Comment: @arshajii, Added code in the main question explaining which is the problem.

Comment: @Brinnis, Added code in the main question explaining which is the problem.

Comment: @Jaffar Ramay, Added code in the main question explaining which is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a `NullPointerException` this cannot be due to the string `" "` you pass to the split function - that is definitely not null. It seems that the `String s` that you get as a parameter of your `splitReceivedString` method is `null` for any reason.

Comment: Well, yes, it could be. I'm developing a bluetooth app based on the bluetoothChat exmample. The string that I'm inserting there, is a string that I receive via bluetooth, so I get it from the variable `readString` from the handler. I tought that it was right 'cause when making a toast to this variable, I see in the app the string `2b 00 00`. So, what I could do?

Comment: its because splitting the string using .split(" ") wont return anything since " " is not correct regualr expression syntax which is required for the .split method. Thus the null pointer.

Comment: @KBusc: split never returns `null`. See here, too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6902125/55787

Comment: @chiccodoro, Added code in the main question explaining which is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Insert some output (System.out.println or other) to debug

- what is your s
- how many elements does separated have
- what is separated[0] (if you only have one element)

Try to use

```
s.split("\\s");
```

to split at any whitespace.

Comment: the "s" variable is a string getted as I say in @chiccodoro's answer from the bluetooth inputstream

Comment: TM, Added code in the main question explaining which is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in a console application. I changed the double quotes to single quotes and there was a spelling mistake oin the method "Split"

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        splitReceivedString("2b 00 00"); //1
    }

    public static string splitReceivedString(String s)
    {
        string[] separated = s.Split(' '); //2
        return separated[1];
    }
```

Comment: if I set single cuotes I get this error: `The method split(String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (Char)`

Comment: Because ' ' is not regular expression syntax

Comment: @beaumondo, Added code in the main question explaining which is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a regular expression to split the string. 
Try like so

```
String splitString = "2b 00 00";
String delim = "[ ]";
//here we split the string wherever we see a character matching
//the inside of our square brackets. In this case a space
String[] splitResults = splitString.split(delim);
```

I have tested this and it works giving the following results

```
splitResults[0] = "2b"
splitResults[1] = "00"  
splitResults[2] = "00"
```

Comment: nothing neither this way. I think that I'm gettin this because of the `readString ` variable from the bluetooth's imputstream.

Comment: Added code in the main question explaining which is the problem.